# How to use "debut"

Tags: word-choice, difference

A. His first new film will **open** tomorrow.

B. His first new film will **debut** tomorrow.

C. His first new film will **be shown** tomorrow.

I am wondering if those mean the same, if not, would you please correct me?

Answer (score 1):

> A. His first new film will open tomorrow.
>
> B. His first new film will debut tomorrow.

These typically mean the same thing; a person's first new film will be shown for the first time tomorrow.

> C. His first new film will be shown tomorrow.

This can have a different meaning - namely, that this is not the first showing of the film. For example, a local movie theatre can show Steven Spielberg's first movie tomorrow - in which case option C is the only accurate one - but it will not be the first time the movie will be shown.

Option C can be used whenever the first two options can be used, but it can also be used in other periods of time *after* the first showing. Options A and B might be better.

So, to answer the title question, "debut" can be used *only for the first showing*, generally performed/shown in public.